# How can I disable a specific USB device on boot in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb

I have a malfunctioning USB device that causes the following error on boot:

```
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
usb 2-3: device not accepting address 6, error -62
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
usb 2-3: device not accepting address 6, error -62
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
usb 2-3: device not accepting address 6, error -62
usb usb2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I have to wait for it to timeout before I can input my dm-crypt password to continue the boot process.

Is there a way to disable that device so that the kernel doesn't care about it at all? I can't unplug it because it's builtin. I don't have anything I use on usb2 too so it's OK to disable the whole hub. I tried to blacklist `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/modalias` and `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/2-0:1.0/modalias` (all modalias I can find under usb2) but that didn't work.

EDIT: lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 6100 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:15.0 DMA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO DMA Controller (rev 03)
00:15.4 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO GSPI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Limited 720p FaceTime HD Camera
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)
04:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801 (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 NHI [Falcon Ridge 4C 2013]
08:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL2210 Thunderbolt Controller [Port Ridge 1C 2011]
09:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL2210 Thunderbolt Controller [Port Ridge 1C 2011]
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
```

Comment: Could you please post "lspci" list ? with the usb controller info ?

Comment: @dExIT I've updated with lspci output.

Comment: Linux flavor, and if possible Kernel version, and if possible could you tell me the MoBo version/Laptop version on which this is happening ? And if possible also if you think you know what could be the culprit (always plugged in) please explain what is it.

Comment: For linux flavor and kernel run : "uname -a"

Comment: Try this approach: https://superuser.com/questions/575887/how-to-disable-device-in-linux-debian-wheezy?rq=1

Comment: @dExIT I'm on Arch Linux, kernel 4.12.4. That device is built into the laptop (it might be a SD card reader) and it is broken. But I don't want to fix it (that'll take time and effort and I don't use it anyway). I want Linux to ignore the device, not the whole class of devices I can plug into other USB ports so I can't blacklist the xhci_hcd module.

Comment: Have you checked if you can disable it in the BIOS?

Comment: @xenoid it's a macbook and there is no BIOS.